# No Ethernet connection access

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I have community Wi-Fi. No access to Ethernet (no wired connection). There is a box that must stay in my closet. The box has a modem, router, and wap (Wireless Access Point).

Each apartment receives certain Mbps. The Wi-Fi speed is fine. I need a wired connection (Ethernet connection) for my job. It is a requirement.

I can not get my own cable service. I have to keep the community Wi-Fi which is provided by my apartment complex. Can I just plug in a Ethernet cable to the router which is the small white box on the top right?

The white larger box on top left is the wireless access point. The black box below it is the Arris modem, the box on top right in the picture is the hex router with Ethernet ports.

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

[image: img 3]

Comment: if its not your equipment, you shouldnt touch it, for many reasons.

Comment: As @Keltari points out.. you probably *shouldn't* .. but your assumptions are correct.   You are likely to find success in running Ethernet right out of that router and out under the door with zero implications.  You certainly will not hurt anything (from a technical point of view) by trying.  To be clear, I am not talking about a moral or legal point of view.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas.. Thanks for your honest opinion. I appreciate it.

Comment: It might help to clarify what community wifi is in this context (shared wifi for the whole building? they run APs per apartment?), and what the 'actual' problem is - poor signal? slow speeds?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Each apartment receives a certain mbps. The Wi-Fi speed is fine. I need a wired connection (Ethernet connection) for my job. It is a requirement.

Comment: For the future - knowing why is sometimes helpful - I added it now to the question for you. If your work requires a wired connection, you should ask whoever is managing the network to arrange it. However they may ask _why_ it is necessary. It would prevent anyone from snooping the wireless traffic, but as a security measure it's really woefully inadequate - for real data protection you'd need a VPN to the company network, internet connection method is irrelevant. Another reason I can think of would be some kind of time-sensitive traffic but since the Wi-Fi speed is fine...?

Comment: @Peregrino69   I asked my building management about having my own personal cable, and I was told no, and that everyone has to be on the same community Wi-Fi plan. My employer does have a VPN.  I do have a fast speed WiFi connection. Hopefully I’m not told by my employer that it is mandatory to have a wired connection. As it is stated in the job requirements. It’s a new job that I’m about to start, and I was just worried, and trying to be prepared in advance. Thanks, I feel a little more at ease .

Comment: Isn't it just fabulous to have a flexible, accommodating environment? </sarcasm> A specific requirement for a wired connection sounds really odd to me. As long as there's a proper VPN, the data is encrypted in your laptop and decrypted on the other end. Breaking the encryption with today's tools takes years, so I don't see an issue :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thank you. You made my day! Enjoy your weekend! 

Answer (score 0):

> Can I just plug in a Ethernet cable to the router which is the small white box on the top right?

From the technical side: Probably, or probably not.

Based on the way cables are connected, it's somewhat likely that the hEX is still in its close-to-default configuration, with port 1 being configured as a "WAN" port and ports 2-5 being bridged together in a "LAN" interface (which matches the modem being on port 1 and the access point being on... port 2? port 5? both at the same time? I can't quite tell from the photo). Guessing from that, the free ports 3 and 4 will also be assigned to the same LAN.

There is no guarantee of that, however, as RouterBOARD firmware is *very* flexible in its configuration (there's no built-in assumption of any port being reserved for any particular function). The ports might be disabled, or not assigned to the same bridge, or require 802.1X authentication, or someone might just notice an "unused" port being up and come to investigate.

Comment: Thanks, I’m just going to use my Wi-Fi. Hopefully everything will work out!